# Cat command with sed

Tags: json, awk, sed, cat

I have a file:

```
{
  "test_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "pm": "30",
      "mp": "40"
    }
  ],
  "test": [
    "id",
    "pm",
    "mp"
  ]
}
```

I want to extract `test_data`. Output:

```
"test_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "pm": "30",
      "mp": "40"
    }
],
```

I try this command: `cat myFile | sed -n '/^"test_data": \[$/,/^\],$/p'`

But it's don't work. An idea ?

Thanks you !

Comment: I suggest to use `jq` (Command-line JSON processor) for this.

Answer (score 2):

`jq` seems the right tool for the job :

```
$ jq '.|{test_data:.test_data}' filename
{
  "test_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "pm": "30",
      "mp": "40"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : Thanks, You need to install `jq` first which is ready obtainable thru `apt`. The file extension need not be `jq`. The only requirement is that file should contain valid `json`. To check that you may run `jq '.' filename`. And do a `man jq`  some extensive info :-)

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** With `sed`

```
sed -n '/"test_data"/,/],/p'   Input_file
```

***OR:*** as per OP, OP needs to append a string/data after a line matches:

```
sed -n '/"test_data"/,/],/p;/],/s/$/"test"/p'  Input_file
```

***OR2:*** If one wants to add an another file's content to a match then following may help in same:

```
sed -n '/"test_data"/,/],/p;/],/r another_file'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Following simple `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/test_data/, /],/' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
  "test_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "pm": "30",
      "mp": "40"
    }
  ],
```

***Logic for above solutions:***

***For*** `sed`: `-n` option in `sed` will turn OFF the printing of any line till it is explicitly mentioned to print it, then by doing `/"test_data"/,/],/` I am letting `sed` know that I need to get the data from test_data to till `,/]` and mentioning `p` after that will make sure those lines which are coming in this range are getting printed here/

***For*** `awk`: Simply mentioning the range from `/"test_data"/,/],/` and not mentioning any action so when any line comes into this range condition becomes true and since no action mentioned so by default print of that line happens then.

Comment: I have to use sed and no awk :/

Comment: @Crazy, please check my `sed` solution now added it too.

Comment: Thanks ! And if I want add text after } ? (in your output example)

Comment: @Crazy, kindly do let me know which kind of text and what are conditions to add it too? So that a generic solution could be provided.

Comment: Add a content of file after } (in the same line). 
There may be more than one information in test_data

Comment: @Crazy, please check my solution after OR and let me know if that helps you. `sed -n '/"test_data"/,/],/p;/],/s/$/"test"/p'  Input_file`

Comment: Last thing: I use this command (i work with your example): `sed "/^[[:blank:]]*\"data_$2\": \[$/,/^[[:blank:]]*],*$/ {s/^[[:blank:]]*}$/&test/}"` How to replace test with a content of another file ?

Comment: @Crazy, check my OR2 code now, also please don't change your questions frequently in a single question, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Sorry .. And thanks ! But I don't uderstand how to implement /r another file in my command (in my previous comment) ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try that with gnu

```
csplit -s -z infile %test_data%-1 /],/1;rm xx01;echo "Add Text here" >> xx00;cat xx00
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is **`jq`** tool:

```
jq 'del(.test)' inputfile
```

The output:

```
{
  "test_data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "pm": "30",
      "mp": "40"
    }
  ]
}
```